# How to add search in meteor todo app example

Tags: javascript, search, meteor

I try to add a search field in the todo app example of meteorjs, but I don't know how to do it.

I can get the value of the search field with a event but after that I don't know how to filter the "Tasks" collection.

Anyone know how to handle this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without any fulltext utility, you can use regex on a `Collection.find` like so:

```
Tasks.find({text: new RegExp(searchTerm,"ig")});
```